# Android: Uploading a text file periodically?

Tags: android, logging

If I want to upload a text file containing some game stats to a web server for testing purpose, which approach is the best? Do I write a service along with my application and then upload the log file once it reaches a specific size? Or do I embed the logic into my application and then do it during idle times?

Comment: Did u successfully upload the file periodically? if so can u tell me how to upload files  as am trying for this now

Answer (score 1):

I would use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to peridocially initiate the upload. The perform the upload from a [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: Just a quick question, if the Handler resides inside the activity, would that block the UI?

Comment: No as the Handler is not blocking it asynchonously delivers messages to your activity thread. Here is a simple example http://almondmendoza.com/2009/01/05/using-handler-in-android/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to trigger the upload periodically as part of an `Activity` (i.e in response to a user action), then using an `AsyncTask` is probably the easiest way to do it.  You'd only need to use a `Service` if you want the upload to happen in the background without being initiated by the user or attached to a UI element.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a Service because you will be using network connectivity and the phone's resources when the user doesn't expect it.

Do it the lazy way and under the bonnet while the app is running using the `AsyncTask`. If your file never grows above 100k it should be quick enough to send it through. If you are thinking about uploading bigger files >500k then you should probably consider chunking the file in small bit as you need to bear in mind that cell connectivity is flakey.